# Different ways to access tuples created with zip built-in function

Tags: python

I want to sort a tuple of integers(in decreasing order) and I then want to save a tuple with the order of indices after sorting in a set. The following piece of code does the job:

```
my_set = set()

l = (1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21)
my_set.add(list(zip(*sorted(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)))[0])
```

If I evaluate `my_set` I now have `{(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)}`

I was trying to do the same with the following code(i for indices, v for values):

```
my_set.add(i for i, v in zip(*sorted(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)))
```

It doesn't work in the same way. The set becomes `{ <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f82e49ce360>}`

Why is it that if I feed the zip result into a list I can access the tuples inside but I can't use the other syntax? 
Is there an alternative way of obtaining some tuple created by zip without having to feed into a list and then indexing into it?

Comment: Because, generators are hashable!

Comment: `()` creates a generator not a tuple comprehension, you want `tuple()` I guess

Comment: @Chris_Rands Turns out the problem is a little deeper than that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the output that `zip` returns.

```
>>> list(zip(*sorted(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)))
[(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0), (21, 15, 10, 6, 3, 1)]
```

It's *always* going to be a list of 2 tuples - one tuple being the argsorted indices, and the other being the actual sorted items.

First up, you don't realise this because you're hashing a generator inside a set... but when you decide to exhaust the generator, be prepared for a

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

In summary, you're iterating over `zip` incorrectly. You don't even *need* to iterate over zip, if it's just the first tuple you're interested in.

What you should *instead* do, is use `next`;

```
>>> my_set.add(next(zip(*sorted(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))))
>>> my_set
{(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)}
```

Which gets you just the first tuple.

Comment: `next` is exactly what I was looking for this problem. More generally if I need to access any other tuple that is the result of zip I will always have to feed the zip result into list or tuple and then index into that, right? Or call `next` a bunch of times...

Comment: @plx It would be simpler to convert to a list/tuple of tuples and index.